# iterating over rows in a column an checking for condition

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Am fairly new to excel programming and was trying some statements and condition.  I have an excel sheet with the following format:

```
Col. A    Col. B    Col. C
  03        1          1 
  02        0          0
```

What am trying to achieve is that if column A has 03( a new column should be added at the end) saying 'Comm' else it should say 'Retail'. I have the following code at the moments:

```
For Each rngCell in Range("O:O")
    If rngCell.value = "03"
      rngCell.value = "Comm"
    Else
      rngCell.value = "Retail"
    End If
Next
```

Can someone help me with the code?

Code Updated

Comment: One thing, your code is doing the opposite of your description. Whether that be a typo or not, you want to switch Comm and Retail around. Secondly, what you are doing is changing the value of the cell that exists in the range you are looping though, so you are replacing your cell values.

Comment: So do you want the values of "Comm" and "Retail" to be in a separate workbook? Or just in a separate column?

Comment: Your code does not follow your narrative.

Comment: @Jordan It would be good if I could create a column in the active workbook and then copy the entire content into a separate workbook. I believe I have no issues copying the contents.

Comment: @ScottCraner i have updated the narrative.

Comment: @SageMohan, so you are looking to input in column D, in the same row as the given cell, either "Retail" or "Comm" depending on the value in column A?

Comment: @Kyle yes, That is correct.

Comment: Assuming you have headers, and data starts in A2, use `=IF(A2="03","Comm","Retail")` then drag down to the last row of data.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track for sure. I would suggest specifying in your `FOR EACH` loop that the property of the range upon which you are iterating is it's `.cells` collection like:

```
 For Each rngCell in Range("O:O").Cells
```

I believe that is the "default" property in this context, but it's better safe than sorry as Ranges also have "Areas" which then have Cells and you might end up iterating through the wrong thing some day.

To set the value of another cell based on the cell/range you are on, you can use offset:

```
For Each rngCell in Range("O:O")
    If rngCell.value = "03"
      rngCell.offset(0,3).value = "Comm"
    Else
      rngCell.offset(0,3).value = "Retail"
    End If
Next
```

You could also refer to the rngCell's row and supply your own column:

```
For Each rngCell in Range("O:O")
    If rngCell.value = "03"
      Range("R" & rngCell.Row).value = "Comm"
    Else
      Range("R" & rngCell.Row).value = "Retail"
    End If
Next
```